# What are these little square symbols in Swift 3 code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, syntax

Sorry I have been away from programming for a while (since before Swift 3) and even back then I wasn't real good at it.  Anyway I was playing around with SwiftyCam:

https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam

And I notice these squares in the code.  Anyone know what these things are?  Never saw this before, and not sure if it's new with Swift 3 or if I just haven't come across them. Example:

```
func swiftyCam(_ swiftyCam: SwiftyCamViewController, didFocusAtPoint point: CGPoint) {
   let focusView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "focus"))
   focusView.center = point
   focusView.alpha = 0.0
   view.addSubview(focusView)
}
```

Okay well I can't even paste it.  It's before the word "focus" and there are no quotations it's just (resourceName: ***insert square here***focus)

I hope this makes sense and sorry if it's a dumb question I just don't know how to look something like this up because you can't type squares int he docs or anything.

Comment: Pictures or it didn't happen.

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The little squares are actually text. They just appear in Xcode as little squares with the name of the image after it. e.g.

[image]

As you can see in your pasted code, it's just this in text form:

```
#imageLiteral(resourceName: "focus")
```

The above is basically equivalent to:

```
UIImage(named: "focus")
```

Another one of these cool literals is `#colorLiteral`. e.g.

```
#colorLiteral(red: 0.4131736755, green: 0.7676505446, blue: 0.4273042679, alpha: 1)
```

These literals are just syntactic sugar that makes your code look prettier:

[image]